# ¿Cómo imprimir comentarios de un archivo en windows xp con la consola cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd, msdos

Esta semana he estado probando a imprimir una lista de archivos en un `.txt` usando la consola de comandos CMD de Windows XP, estos archivos llevan todos incluidos un comentario.

Pero usando la consola de comando no consigo imprimir en pantalla dicho comentario, uso el comando `dir` para imprimir el nombre del archivo, pero no se que comando hay que poner en la consola para que me imprima el comentario que escribí en el archivo.

¿Me podéis ayudar y decirme que comando es el que imprime comentarios de archivos en CMD?

GRACIAS de antemano.

Comment: Eh, a qué te refieres con comentario de archivo?

Comment: Con dir /q muestras toda la información de ficheros y directorios, no se si es lo que preguntas

Comment: a comentarios me refiero a pulsar encima del archivo con botón derecho, luego pincho en propiedades, resumen y ahí aparece la opción de escribir comentario. y dir /q no funciona. @el.trasgu